# Install npm package from commit in pull request

Tags: git, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to npm install this specific commit https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone/pull/464/commits/dd59106b48c34d2f2557b0ba17adea52aa666036

I use : `npm install --save vue2-dropzone#dd59106b48c34d2f2557b0ba17adea52aa666036`

But the code installed in node_modules does not have the code from the commit I asked.

How can I do that ?

thanks

Comment: I think you have to install it using a git url. npm only keeps published _versions_, and does not have knowledge of commits.

Comment: I think if you want the closest version use `npm i vue2-dropzone@3.5.8`. Otherwise look at the docs https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the commit did not include the built file (the code was correct in the src directory but not in the dist directory). More over the src directory is not part of the installed package, it is just available in the repo. So that was not easy to find. I had to clone the repo locally and build the package myself to get the correct code in the dist directory.

So @evolutionxbox, installing a package from a commit does work.

thanks.